# Spark Dataframe from nested directories with labels

Tags: image, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm trying to read 8 GB of images from [HDFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#Hadoop_distributed_file_system) in a nested directory structure like this:

```
   train_set
   |___dir_0
   |   |___0.jpg
   |   |___1.jpg
   |___dir_2
   |   |___0.jpg
   |   |___1.jpg
```

I'm using Scala and Spark, and I've tried all the documented solutions, but I can't get out of this. I would like to have a Dataframe with columns "image" and "label", where label is the name (or an index) of the image's parent directory.

Comment: In a general manner you should add the code you tried on your question.

Answer (score 1):

When you read images as dataframe, you will get one struct column called as image. One of the sub column of image is origin which marks the parent directory.

```
spark.read.format("image").load("train_set/dir_0/*.jpg", "train_set/dir_2/*.png")
  .selectExpr("image", "image.origin as label").show
```

If you are using spark with version >= 3.0.0 then you can use [some options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html) instead of passing multiple file paths as an argument to load() method.